# alert followed by a Response.Redirect() doesn't shoot the alert msg

Tags: javascript, asp.net, page-init

I have an alert message and followed by a Response.Redirect block in Page_Init

The Response.Redirect works and redirects to a spectic page.
But the alert msg is not showing.

I need the user to click the OK button in the alert msg after that only the page should rediret..

Please help.

Sample code:

ScriptManager.RegisterCleintScriptBlock(this,this.GetType(),"alert('Success')",true);
Response.Redirect("index.aspx",false);

Answer (score 0):

It will never work because the context is lost. The `alert()` should be done in `index.aspx.cs`.

Here is the possible implementation:

```
Response.Redirect("index.aspx?query=alert",false);
```

And in index.aspx.cs `Page_Load`:

```
if(Request["query"]=="alert")
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(),"key","alert('Success')",true); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not do it in pure JavaScript?

```
<script>
    (function() {
        alert("Success");
        window.location = "/index.aspx";
    })();
</script>
```